# Gradle: could not set unknown property 'classDumpFile' in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jacoco

I have been searching through the Internet and asking on irc chats but none of them were or did not give any answer for trying to solve my problem.

I am trying to make my project to use `JaCoCo` on `Intellij` IDE, the tests are going to be done in a `Jenkins` server, i have set some settings in my gradle.build file for `JaCoCo` but build compilation fails saying `Could not set unknown property 'classDumpFile' for object of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension.`

The build file is like this:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jacoco{
    toolVersion = '0.7.6.201602180812'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
}
test{
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
```

this is a gradle file generated by `IntelliJ` when creating the project and i have been adding some dependencies manually, now the developer that is managing the `jenkins` server told me to use these `JaCoCo` settings for `sonarQube` to work well, `IntelliJ` fails to make any compilation but when submitting the code to `Jenkins` it works fine.

I have been searching why does this happens and i have found out this might be due to gradle version and should use `classDumpDir` instead, this makes `IntelliJ` work but `Jenkins` server fails to build the project.

I believe this might be due to gradle version or something but i am still learning how to work with `Java` and `IntelliJ`, other developers are working with `Eclipse` and they do not get this error but i don't want to switch to `Eclipse` cause i am already too comfortable with `IntelliJ`

In case is necessary here are the versions i am using:

- CLI Gradle version: 2.10
- Java version: Ubuntu openjdk 1.8.0_151
- IntelliJ version: 2017.3.4 Community Edition

Comment: Can you build project by Gradle from command line? Try using different jacoco plugin version. Could be that the `classDumpFile` property you are using in build.gradle does not exist in that particular plugin version. Try also different Gradle version (in Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle).

Comment: @Andrey i have tried changing the version of jacoco and stil i get this error, the problem is that i have to set that version of jacoco so the jenkins server can catch all coverage reports, however i think this might be a gradle version issue on which i have been trying multiple methods on how to change the version but i don't even know which version the IDE is using

Comment: IDE is using Gradle, specified in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long hours of searching, testing and failing i have finally found the way to fix this issue.

I have found out in the directory `gradle/wrapper` there is a file with the gradle properties, in this file there was a variable that defines which gradle to use and on my file it was set to use gradle 4.5:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

i've asked the DevOps engineer which gradle version jenkins is using and he said it should be 3.0 so i changed the `distributionUrl` value to use 3.0 version and it works

Comment: Similarly in my case, changing version from `4.8.1` to `2.9` helped.

Comment: Since you are referring to gradle wrapper here, I'm guessing this from the Question did not end up being related?  `CLI Gradle version: 2.10`

Answer (score 18):

Looks like they changed the Variable, from classDumpFile to classDumpDir.

```
test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
```

This worked for me

Comment: This also worked for me on my local machine but the jenkins server fails with this settings

Comment: With gradle wrapper version `4.8.1`, this helps get past the error in the title; but in my case, subsequent errors followed, and I instead still had to downgrade gradle wrapper version, similar to [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076022/1357094)